# Use two tables on a two-to-many relationship or use three tables with a pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Basically, I have 2 tables in my database: Games and Teams.

Every Game must have 2 teams, so it's a two-to-many relationship.

Should I use 2 foreign keys in my Games table pointing to the 2 teams in the Teams table and have a one-to-many relationship, or use many-to-many relationship with a third table to link the games and teams table?

Im using Laravel 6.5 for the project, so I guess im using Eloquent to implement it.

```
Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_a_id');
            $table->foreign('team_a_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_b_id');
            $table->foreign('team_b_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->unsignedInteger('team_a_score');
            $table->unsignedInteger('team_b_score');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->boolean('finished');
        });
```

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('abbreviation');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This are the two tables I have created by now, is this the correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Many to Many [Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). In that case the Game Modal could have multiple Teams and vice-versa.

Hence the migrations would be like:

```
  Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->boolean('finished');
  });

  Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('abbreviation');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->timestamps();
  });

  Schema::create('game_team', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('game_id');
        $table->integer('team_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('score');
        $table->timestamps();
  });
```

Comment: Is there any precise reason I should go with the pivot table way and not the 2 foreign keys way? I feel like im still a novice in terms of querying a mysql database throught eloquent and relationships.

Comment: Using a pivot table could help you establish Many To Many Relationships easily and make use of laravel's respective methods.